# Using Forever-Monitor in Node-Webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, forever

I'm trying to get forever-monitor working in node-webkit. I've used it in node express applications in the past without any problems, but can't seem to make it work in this case.

I have an index.html file which references the server.js script which contains the following code which is executed on launch:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
  max: 3,
  silent: false,
  options: []
});


child.on('exit', function () {
  console.log('app.js has exited after 3 restarts');
});

child.on('start', function () {
  console.log('app.js has started');
});

child.on('restart', function (){
  console.log('app.js restarted');
});


child.start();
```

The app.js file consists of the following code:

```
var Q = require('q'),
  gui = require('nw.gui'),
  express = require('express'),
  path = require('path'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  Config = require('./api/utils/config'),
  SessionService = require('./api/services/SessionService'),
  menu = new gui.Menu(),
  exec = require('child_process').exec,
  child;

var app = express();
var trayActive = false;
var tray;
var routePath = path.resolve('./api/controllers'); // Dynamically pull in all routes and pass in application

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

fs.readdirSync(routePath).forEach(function (file) {
  var filePath = path.join(routePath, file);
  require(filePath)(app, openFile);
});

var server = app.listen(Config.expressPort, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port: ', server.address().port);     
  gui.Window.get().show();
});
```

When I 'npm start' I get the following output:

> [970:0602/191500:INFO:CONSOLE(15)] ""app.js has
>   started"", source:
>   file:///Users/chris/webstorm-projects/myapp/server.js (15) execvp():
>   No such file or directory

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, and if you know of a working alternative method to accomplish restarts in node-webkit please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The latest version fixed some bug regarding launching child processes. Does it work for you?

Comment: I don't have time to test it now, but maybe someone will chime in. I ended up using launchctl (node-webkit app is packaged for OSX) to restart the app if it crashed unexpectedly. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

for my case I was not able to require('nw.gui')